# Ruby __FILE__ has the wrong case for directories

Tags: ruby

This is the first time I've seen this. `__FILE__` is using a lower case name for the "projects" directory in the path:

```
__FILE__
=> "/Users/benjohnson/projects/primaryapp/config/boot.rb"

`pwd`
=> "/Users/benjohnson/Projects/primaryapp"
```

I thought `__FILE__` was provided by ruby, there is no way to alter it, which would make this a ruby bug, correct? Any idea how I can continue to debug / fix? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are using a case-insensitive filesystem? (Like HFS+ which is Mac standard)

Comment: What kind of filesystem is this? FAT32 (older external hard drives, USB sticks and memory cards), exFAT (newer external hard drives, USB sticks and memory cards), HFS, HFS+ (default in recent versions of OSX), NTFS (default on recent versions of Windows), HPFS and many others are case-insensitive.

Comment: Yes, I'm on a mac, HFS+ file system. The strange thing is that this only recently started happening.

Comment: Are you sure it just started happening? Things don't just change like that. Honestly, on a case insensitive filesystem you might not have noticed it the difference.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Ruby problem. `__FILE__` can only be created by the Ruby interpreter since only it knows what file it's currently processing, and it gets that information as it's running so the information is as current as possible. `pwd` gets its information by asking the operating system, and doesn't necessarily reflect the same path that the Ruby interpreter is using. Perhaps you have two directories, "/Users/benjohnson/projects" and "/Users/benjohnson/Projects" and one of them contains an invisible character making them unique? `ls -B /Users/benjohnson` should show that.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I realize it's an old question, but can you add more details?